# Localizing Winforms for different customers?

Tags: c#, winforms

For the sake of this question, let's assume that we have an entity called CategoryType and a corresponding form for adding/editing/deleting category types.

Now, some customers want to have the labels changed from, for example, 'Category Type' to 'Product Type'.

What is a good strategy to handle this kind of 'localizing'?

If one solution is to use resource files, would it be necessary to define customer-specific conditional compilation symbols and load the specific resource file accordingly?

Comment: Use Resource files? If you need more specific answer your question needs to be specific.

Comment: For your edit: No conditional compilation. Just ship the right resource file for the right customer.

Comment: May be more flexible approach will be set headers for labels in datatable. Then every user can edit them for his needs.